# Fadeout function not working in all browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

i have following function but it is not working in IE.
and please tell some problem if my function have any

```
function fadeOut(id,funcs){
    if(ge(id)==null){
        doit=true;
    }
    timer=10;
    t=1;
    ge(id).style.opacity=t;
    fo_tym=setInterval(function(){
        if(ge(id)==null){
            clearInterval(fo_tym);
            return;
        }
        if(t<0){
            funcs();
            clearInterval(fo_tym);
            return; 
        }
        t=t-0.01;
        ge(id).style.opacity=t;

    },0);
}
```

`ge(id)` is function which find element in DOM and `funcs()` will be called after fadeOut Finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of IE?  IE prior to 9 used filter attributes rather than style.opacity.  Example:

```
var hasOpacity = 'opacity' in ge(id).style;

// ...

if (hasOpacity) {
    ge(id).style.opacity=t;
} else {
    ge(id).style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + t*100 + ')';
}
```

Comment: IE 8 and all above and i want to make that can work in all browser

Comment: and this function also working very slow as compared to firefox and chrome